# POSH Import-Excel to Export-Csv - Blank Excel Files give unexpected csv output

Tags: powershell

Working scenario - Excel with Data records / Non-Empty Excel File - Same Code

[Excel Input 2 : Excel Input File with records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sG78z.png)

[Csv output 2: Csv output for Excel File with Data records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QCxw.png)

Not Working Scenario - Excel File with no data records / Empty file - Same Code

[Excel Input 1: Blank Input Excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGWmE.png)

[Csv Output 1: Csv output file with Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ijc6.png)

I'm using PowerShell to merge multiple excel files into 1, without having to install MSExcel on server. I'm doing that by converting all excel to csv files and then merging all csv files into 1 csv file.

The Excel files row header starts from Row 5. If the Excel files have any rows after row header, the csv file is rendered as expected, but if the Excel file is blank after the row header at Row 5, the csv output file has 3 rows - 1st and 3rd rows have excel row headers and the 2nd row is blank.

```
$Files = GCI 'E:\SharedExcel\Data Extracts\Project Journals\Temp Server 
Downloads\*' | ?{$_.Extension -Match "xlsx?"} | select -ExpandProperty 
FullName
ForEach($File in $Files) {
$InFile = Get-Item $File
$OutFile= $InFile.FullName.replace($InFile.Extension,".csv")
Import-Excel $Infile.FullName -StartRow 5 | Export-Csv $OutFile - 
NoTypeInformation
}
```

Expected result : If the Excel File does not have any records after row header at Row #5, the csv should just have row header once with no records. The Actual csv file has 3 rows- 1st and 3rd row have row headers and 2nd row is blank.

[Successful Powershell script execution Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HKQB.png) My script runs successfully producing the 4 newly created csv files from the 4 excel files.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/6.5.1/Content/ImportExcel.psm1):

```
.PARAMETER StartRow
       The row from where we start to import data, all rows above the StartRow are disregarded. By default this is the first row.
       When the parameters ‘-NoHeader’ and ‘-HeaderName’ are not provided, this row will contain the column headers that will be used as property names. When one of both parameters are provided, the property names are automatically created and this row will be treated as a regular row containing data.
```

Without an additional parameter set, the referenced row will be treated as property names. I think you are passing a list of property names with the values equal to the property names to the `Export-Csv` cmdlet.